# sas DI JOBS troubleshoot and Monitor in unix

Tags: sas, sas-dis

If sas is installed on windows os then How to troubleshoot or catch its performance of sas DI jobs on unix? using any tools or commands or By using nmon?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Performance of each job in SAS Data Integration studio can be measured using a few techniques

1. **ARM logging** - Enabling/utilizing the Audit and Performance Measurement capabilities with SAS (commonly referred to as ARM logging).
2. You can add a parameter **FULLSTIMER=I** in the autoexec.sas for the session or for each session which will help in giving performance stats, there are many a code snippets or tools out there which can parse and give you fancy performance stats on the jobs.
3. I have been exploring a few more things now a days which is provided with SAS 9.4 called **Environment Manager**. This is a daemon which can be configured and give a lot of performance stats and other things. It is web based and a very handy tool for Admins.

Hope this information helps!